# Visual Designer for Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, wysiwyg

Well guys I have a simple question which may seem stupid - so forgive me.

My client has just asked me (as a favor) to design a single web page that has a header, 2-3 buttons, and 10-15 textboxes and is connected to SQL. Now I know I can do this (the behind-page code) but the problem is that I have no idea on how to actually design the asp page. I have very basic knowledge of html and no knowledge of CSS so I cant "code" the design.

What I require is WYSIWYG designer for asp, so I can drag and drop (kind of win forms in VS) buttons, textboxes and headings. The visual designer in VS for asp is no good for me. So is there any software (free or not) out there that can help me out? I need to do this in a day or two so I don't really have time to learn CSS/HTML.

Comment: I appreciate you don't have the time to learn HTML and CSS for your current project, but there is simply no good substitute for writing it directly.  It really would be in your own interest to spend some time (obviously when you have that time) to get your hands dirty.  You'll be glad you did in the long run.  (Edit: I simply don't use WYSIWYG editors, so I can't recommend any, hence this is a comment, not an answer)

Comment: I hate recommending this - but since you're on a tight timeline and you don't know client design, could you just use a table for the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Visual Web Developer](http://www.asp.net/vwd) is probably your best bet. It's free and provided by Microsoft, so it'll work and play nicely with the standard .NET control set. It's not as full featured as Visual Studio is, but for a free tool I don't think you're going to get any better than this.

That being said, you really need to learn the client end of developing ASP.NET, since there's only so far any WYSIWYG editor is going to go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, let me look into it. If it does what I need to do, I will choose your answer.